# What do Ada pragmas Static_Elaboration_Desired and Linker_Section mean

Tags: ada, pragma

What do the Ada directive pragmas `Static_Elaboration_Desired` and `Linker_Section` mean? I wasn't able to comprehend the definitions given over internet.

Comment: Can you provide more context please... What is it you are trying to do ?

Answer (score 1):

`Static_Elaboration_Desired` is **not** an Ada pragma.  It is an implementation defined pragma in GNAT:

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gnat_rm/Pragma-Static_005fElaboration_005fDesired.html

You use it, if you want elaboration to be static (i.e. just a part the executable image) rather than happen through executable code.